# Approximating surface with tangent planes

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, graphics3d

I want to reproduce the effect in the figure below, approximating a surface with tangent planes,
[image]
Now I can only use polygons to approximate inside the surface, although a bit similar but it's different. How should I draw each polygon tangent to the surface?

```
Manipulate[Module[{f, d},
  f = Function[{x, y}, 1 - x^2 - y^2];
  d = 2/n;
  Show[Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", Mesh -> None, 
    PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.8]],
   Graphics3D[{
     Table[
      Polygon[{#, #2, f[#, #2]} & @@@ {{i, j}, {d + i, j}, {d + i, 
          d + j}, {i, d + j}}], {i, -1, 1 - d, d}, {j, -1, 1 - d, d}]
     }, PlotRange -> 1]]
  ]
 , {n, 2, 10, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: The animation is wrong.It is impossible to draw a connected piecewise surface tangent to the surface locally.

Comment: Almost only Bezier surface can approximate by piecewise surface,but the animation still does not according to the defination of the area of surface.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer @cvgmt's comment, I would point out this image/animation works because the surface is of the form $z=a-bx^2-by^2$. This implies the vertices of the tangent plane segments over squares coincide at the same height above the surface at every vertex.

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  
  ListPlot3D[
   Table[4 - x^2 - y^2 + 2/n^2, {x, -1, 1, 2/n}, {y, -1, 1, 2/n}],
   NormalsFunction -> None, Mesh -> 2 n - 1, 
   MeshShading -> 
    Flatten[Table[{{1, 1}, {1, 1}} RGBColor[j/n, k/n, 0, 2/3], {j, 
       n}, {k, n}], {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}], 
   DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}],
  
  Plot3D[4 - x^2 - y^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> LightBlue, Mesh -> 2 n - 1],
  
  Plot3D[0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
   Mesh -> Max[n - 1, 1], 
   MeshShading -> Table[RGBColor[j/n, k/n, 0], {j, n}, {k, n}], 
   PlotStyle -> RGBColor[1/2, 1/2, 0]],
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 3/2}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0, 4.5}},
   Lighting -> "Neutral"
  ],
 
 {n, 1, 10, 1}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: （+1）Parabolic curves or surfaces are good enough!

Answer (score 7):

To get an approximation to your surface we first need the function and its gradient;

```
f[{x_, y_}] = (1 - x^2 - y^2);
grad[{x_, y_}] = Grad[f[{x, y}], {x, y}];
```

Then we create a 2D grid of points {x,y}, where the tangent planes will touch the surface:

```
centers = Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {x, -1, 1, 1/d}, {y, -1, 1, 1/d}], 1];
```

For this 2D centers we define a function, that takes a 2D center and calculates the 2D coordinates of the four 2D vertices of the tangent plane polygons:

```
vertices[cen_] := 
  Append[cen + #, f[cen] + grad[cen] . # ] & /@ ( 
    1/(2 d) {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}});
```

With this we can calculate the 3D vertices of the tangent plane polygon:

```
tan = vertices /@ centers;
```

Finally we draw the tangent plane together with the surface and packe everything into a Manipulate:

```
f[{x_, y_}] = (1 - x^2 - y^2);
grad[{x_, y_}] = Grad[f[{x, y}], {x, y}];

Manipulate[
 vertices[cen_] := 
  Append[cen + #, f[cen] + grad[cen] . # ] & /@ ( 
    1/(2 d) {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}});
 centers = Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {x, -1, 1, 1/d}, {y, -1, 1, 1/d}], 1];
 tan = vertices /@ centers;
 
 Show[Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.6], Polygon /@ tan}], 
  Plot3D[f[{x, y}], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]]
 , {d, 1, 10, 1}, TrackedSymbols :> {d}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

- Thanks @Michael E2 point out that quadratic paraboloid work. Here we use the definiton of differential of function to get the tangent plane for 2-variables function,see `df` as in the code.
- And we treat the general form of quadratic paraboloid `f[x,y]=a-b*x^2-c*y^2;` or any other differentiable function `f[x,y]=Sin[x + Cos[y]];`.

```
Clear[f, df, plot, data];
f[x_, y_] = 
  RandomReal[{0, 3}] - RandomReal[{2, 3}] x^2 - RandomReal[{2, 3}] y^2;
(*f[x_,y_]=1-x^2-y^2; *)
df[f_, {x0_, y0_}] = 
  f[x0, y0] + {Derivative[1, 0][f][x0, y0], 
      Derivative[0, 1][f][x0, y0]} . (## - {x0, y0}) &;
plot = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, Mesh -> None];

data = Table[
   regs = MeshPrimitives[
     ArrayMesh[ConstantArray[1, {n, n}], 
      DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], 2];
   Graphics3D[{Table[({x, y} |-> {x, y, 
           df[f, RegionCentroid@reg]@{x, y}}) @@@ 
        MeshCoordinates[reg] // Polygon, {reg, regs}], plot[[1]], 
     RegionProduct[#, Point[{f[1, 1]}]] & /@ regs}, BoxRatios -> 1, 
    Boxed -> False], {n, 1, 10}];
ListAnimate[data, AnimationRunning -> True, 
 ControlPlacement -> Bottom]
```

[image]

### TODO

I want to replace `RegionCentroid@reg` to `RandomPoint@reg` in the code to get some general definition of the area of surface,but now it seems need to be revided later since I doesn't know whether we need to use orthogonal projection to project the pieces of the surface to the tangent plane and how?

```
Clear[f, df, plot, data];
f[x_, y_] = 
  RandomReal[{0, 3}] - RandomReal[{2, 3}] x^2 - RandomReal[{2, 3}] y^2;
(*f[x_,y_]=1-x^2-y^2;*)
df[f_, {x0_, y0_}] = 
  f[x0, y0] + {Derivative[1, 0][f][x0, y0], 
      Derivative[0, 1][f][x0, y0]} . (## - {x0, y0}) &;
plot = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, Mesh -> None, 
   PlotPoints -> 80, MaxRecursion -> 4];

data = Table[
   regs = 
    MeshPrimitives[
     ArrayMesh[ConstantArray[1, {n, n}], 
      DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], 2];
   pts = RandomPoint /@ regs;
   Graphics3D[{Table[({x, y} |-> {x, y, 
           Evaluate@df[f, pts[[i]]]@{x, y}}) @@@ 
        MeshCoordinates[regs[[i]]] // Polygon, {i, Length@regs}], 
     plot[[1]], RegionProduct[#, Point[{f[1, 1]}]] & /@ regs}, 
    BoxRatios -> 1, Boxed -> False], {n, 1, 10}];
ListAnimate[data, AnimationRunning -> True, ControlPlacement -> Bottom]
```

[image]

### Test arbitrary function

- Tangent points are `RegionCentroid`.

```
Clear[f, df, plot, regs];
f[x_, y_] = Sin[x*y];
df[f_, {x0_, y0_}] = 
  f[x0, y0] + {Derivative[1, 0][f][x0, y0], 
      Derivative[0, 1][f][x0, y0]} . (## - {x0, y0}) &;
plot = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, PlotPoints -> 60, 
   MaxRecursion -> 4, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Green];
n = 25;
regs = MeshPrimitives[
   ArrayMesh[ConstantArray[1, {n, n}], DataRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 3}}],
    2];
Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5], 
  Table[({x, y} |-> {x, y, df[f, RegionCentroid@reg]@{x, y}}) @@@ 
     MeshCoordinates[reg] // Polygon, {reg, regs}], plot[[1]]}, 
 BoxRatios -> 1, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

- Tangent Points are bottom left.

```
Clear[f, df, plot, n, regs];
f[x_, y_] = Sin[x*y];
df[f_, {x0_, y0_}][{x_, y_}] = 
  f[x0, y0] + {Derivative[1, 0][f][x0, y0], 
     Derivative[0, 1][f][x0, y0]} . ({x, y} - {x0, y0});
plot = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, PlotPoints -> 60, 
   MaxRecursion -> 4, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Darker@Cyan];
n = 25;
regs = MeshPrimitives[
   ArrayMesh[ConstantArray[1, {n, n}], DataRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 3}}],
    2];
Graphics3D[{Opacity[.8], 
  Table[({x, y} |-> {x, y, 
        df[f, First@*Transpose@*RegionBounds@reg]@{x, y}}) @@@ 
     MeshCoordinates[reg] // Polygon, {reg, regs}], plot[[1]]}, 
 BoxRatios -> 1, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]